# How can I solve GET ... 405 (Method Not Allowed) when send data via ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My ajax (in vue component) like this :

```
<template>
    ...
    <a class="text-right" @click="detail">
        Detail
    </a>
    ...
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        ...
        methods:{
            ...
            detail() {
                this.$http.post(window.BaseUrl + '/shop/',{data: JSON.stringify(this.data)}).then(function (response) {
                    ...
                }).catch(function(error){
                    ...
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If user click a link, it will call detail method

In detail method used to send data via ajax

It will routes in laravel

The route like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'shop','as'=>'shop.'], function () {
    Route::post('/', 'ShopController@index');
    ...
});
```

Then the route will call shop controller

The controller like this :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

If the code executed, on the console exist error like this :

> GET http://myshop.dev/shop 405 (Method Not Allowed)

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're having problems with your **routes** and **csrf_token**.

You should read about the http methods [HTTP methods](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html)

Change the `Route::post('/', 'ShopController@index');` to `Route::get('/', 'ShopController@index');`

The error is shown because you did not sent the csrf_token while using post method. While using the get method you are not obligated to include the csrf token.

You can read about it here: [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)

Answer (score 0):

Does window.BaseUrl end with / ?

It could be that laravel attempts to 'sanitize' `window.BaseUrl + '/` (2 /'s next to eachother)

What laravel does in that case is send a 302 redirect, could you check if you see that in the network console of your browser?

If there is a 302, try to make the form match the url that laravel attempts to use.